# Load denied by X-Frame-Options after clicking on follow linkedin button

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a website and want to embed LinkedIn follow button on the site
Refer: https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company

I added a LinkedIn follow button to my site, registered my site URL with LinkedIn.

Scenario:

1. Click the Follow button on my site
2. A popup appears asking for login credentials
3. Logged with correct credentials.
4. Popup closes, my website page refreshes but follow button is removed from website.
5. I refresh the page again, follow widget again appears with count and following text.

Error on browser console:

> `Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.linkedin.com/company/follow/submit?id=<Company Id>&fl=start&src=btn&rd=json&ft=0_2MZDSRL3TZnOwVljzvjnGEkdKYCNzL1pCmG7GZUzmtDgbGCJ60vYC_qf6CcabmUV-kkmaf1In8FlOqBM6Ym3Je&csrfToken=ajax%3A4802512393226623262&trk=cws-btn-follow-0-0&ajax= does not permit cross-origin framing.`

When we check LinkedIn headers, it says `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin`

Comment: Kindly suggest whether someone has faced this problem and has a working solution.

Comment: I am also facing same problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432608/company-follow-button-disappear-after-login-popup-linkedin-issue Thank you.