# Company Follow Button disappear after login popup - Linkedin issue

Tags: yii2, linkedin-api

Company Follow Button disappear after login popup - LinkedIn issue

This is the code which they have provided to me

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="10396143" data-counter="right"></script>
```

Thank you

Comment: needs more info. which login popup? a linkedin one? Is there any error in the browser console?

Comment: Yes popup of linkedin one, error message x-frame object is not from same sender